# Read Meta and an MD5 Hash For Every File On the C Drive Using Java

Tags: java, file, hash, filesystems

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am only learning Java, what I am trying to do is read every file on c:\ and create a md5 hash of that file to compare at a later stage as well as displaying some basic counts and meta. I can't seem to recursively loop over every file and folder in the c:\ drive and I am not sure how to tackle creating an MD5 hash of each file. I am also not sure is this the best approach for so many files.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int FileCount = 0,
        DirCount = 0,
        HiddenFiles = 0,
        HiddenDirs = 0;

    File folder = new File("/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
        Path file = listOfFile.toPath();
        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
        System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
        System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
        System.out.println("isOther: " + attr.isOther());
        System.out.println("isRegularFile: " + attr.isRegularFile());
        System.out.println("isSymbolicLink: " + attr.isSymbolicLink());
        System.out.println("size: " + attr.size());

        if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFile.getName());
            System.out.println("isHidden " + listOfFile.isHidden());

            if (listOfFile.isHidden()) {
                HiddenFiles++;
            }

            System.out.println("getPath " + listOfFile.getPath());
            FileCount++;

        } else if (listOfFile.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFile.getName());
            System.out.println("isHidden " + listOfFile.isHidden());
            System.out.println("getPath " + listOfFile.getPath());

            if (listOfFile.isHidden()) {
                HiddenDirs++;
            }

            DirCount++;
        }

        System.out.println("DirCount " + DirCount);
        System.out.println("FileCount " + FileCount);
        System.out.println("HiddenDirs " + DirCount);
        System.out.println("HiddenFiles " + FileCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create classes that will do it what do you want:

```
File, Folder
```

`File` is already exist, let's create class that has name `XFile`, not good but you will be find something better in future.

```
public class XFile {
    private final File file;

    public XFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String name() {
        return file.getName();
    }

    //other data you want to know, create getters for all wanted information from File.

    public byte[] md5() {
        try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            int tempByte;
            while ((tempByte = input.read()) != -1) {
                md5.update((byte) tempByte);
            }
            return md5.digest();
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

and class `Folder` (that should be in jdk all this time)

```
public class Folder {
    private final File underlyingDir;
    private List<File> elements = null;

    public Folder(File underlyingDir) {
        this.underlyingDir = underlyingDir;
    }

    private void fetchElements() {
        List<File> firstLevelElements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(underlyingDir.listFiles()));
        elements = this.recursive(firstLevelElements, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public List<XFile> files() {
        if (elements == null) {
            fetchElements();
        }
        return elements.stream()
                .filter(File::isFile)
                .map(XFile::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public long foldersCount() {
        if (elements == null) {
            fetchElements();
        }
        return elements.stream()
                .filter(File::isDirectory)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .size();
    }

    public long filesCount() {
        if (elements == null) {
            fetchElements();
        }
        return elements.stream()
                .filter(File::isFile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .size();
    }

    public long hiddenFiles() {
        if (elements == null) {
            fetchElements();
        }
        return elements.stream()
                .filter(File::isFile)
                .filter(File::isHidden)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .size();
    }

    public long hiddenDirs() {
        if (elements == null) {
            fetchElements();
        }
        return elements.stream()
                .filter(File::isDirectory)
                .filter(File::isHidden)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .size();
    }

    private List<File> recursive(List<File> elements, int depth) {
        if (depth == -1) return Collections.emptyList();
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File element : elements) {
            if (element.isDirectory()) {
                depth--;
                result.add(element);
                if (nonNull(element.listFiles())) {
                    result.addAll(recursive(Arrays.asList(element.listFiles()), depth));
                }
            } else {
                result.add(element);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and test class Main

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Folder folder = new Folder(new File("F:/"));
        System.out.println("files " + folder.filesCount());
        System.out.println("folders " + folder.foldersCount());
        System.out.println("hidden dirs " + folder.hiddenDirs());
        System.out.println("hidden files " + folder.hiddenFiles());

        for (XFile file : folder.files()) {
            System.out.printf("\nname: %s MD5 hash %s ", file.name(), Arrays.toString(file.md5()));
        }
    }
}
```